# Relationship between the matrix of a linear application and the matrix of the inverse application

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose we have the following linear application:

$ f : V \rightarrow W \\
     \underline{x} \mapsto M(f)\underline{x}$

I know that there is an inverse linear application, $f^{-1}$ if and only if the linear application $f$ is biyective, which is proven in a very simple way.

Once I have purchased that it is invertible, my question is whether there is any relationship between the matrix associated with the application $f$, $M(f)$, and the matrix associated with the application $f^{-1}$, $M(f^{-1})$.

I, by mere intuition, believe that the relationship would be this one:

$M(f^{-1}) = (M(f))^{-1}$

Am I right? Or there is no relationship between the two matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, yo are right ! Suppose that $f$ is bijective and $f(x)=Mx$. Then, for some quadratic matrix $N$ we have $f^{-1}(y)=Ny$. Hence

$y=f(f^{-1}(y))=f(Ny)=MNy$ for all $y \in W$. In a similar fashion we get $x=NMx$ for all $x \in V$.

Thus: $MN=I_W$ and $NM=I_V$, therefore $N=M^{-1}$.